# AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `country` on serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I'm running into the following error, and been stuck on it the last two weeks. I don't know what it could possibly mean by 'int' object has no attribute 'country' in my case, and country exists in my serializer and model. If I remove `country` from the serializer, I get the same error with `post_code`.

I haven't got a clue what could be going wrong

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `country` on serializer `AddressSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `int` instance.
Original exception text was: 'int' object has no attribute 'country'
```

View:

```
class Address(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AddressPermission]
    queryset = Addresses.objects.all()
    def get_object(self):
        try:
            if self.request.COOKIES['access_token'] is not None:
                obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), user=NewUser.objects.get(id=jwt.decode(self.request.COOKIES['access_token'], settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"])['user_id']))
                self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
                return obj
        except:
            return status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED

    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
```

Serializer:

```
class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('country', 'organization_name', 'administrative_area', 'sub_administrative_area', 'locality', 'post_code', 'thoroughfare', 'premise')
        model = Addresses
```

Model:

```
class Addresses(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    # State/Province
    administrative_area = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    # County/District/Municipality
    sub_administrative_area = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    # the actual street address
    thoroughfare = models.CharField(max_length=95)
    # Apt, suite, or box number
    premise = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    user = models.ForeignKey(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: The problem is not in the Serializer class definition, the problem is you're passing an int instead of data to your serializer. Can you capture the data passed to the serializer class and add it to the post?

Comment: I get that error when doing a Get request, what would be passing an int? Shouldn't it be returning data?

Answer (score 0):

Quickly looking at your code again i think you are getting the error because in your get_object you are returning an int and not a string.

In your exception, try to return an HTTPResponse as:

```
return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I think the reason why when you remove country from the serializer you get the same error on the post_code is because all you other attributes have null=True, blank=True. Country does not have this and the next in line without is post_code. Although both of these should be empty strings anyway when saved.

So try to return an HttpResponse and let's see what happens.

Comment: I'm just making a Get request when this error is thrown, there's no payload. There're two cookies that are a part of that request, but that shouldn't be triggering it. Would the Get request headers help? I'm very lost on what could cause this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: This should be a comment since it does not answer the question.

Comment: @vinkomlacic true. My bad. I changed the answer to a question in the middle of typing.